# MacOS Jenkins: Locating JRE and importing self-signed certificate

Tags: java, macos, ssl, jenkins, self-signed

Newbie using macOS here.

We have Jenkins installed on MacOS.

I need to know which JRE and cacerts it uses because I need to import GitHub enterprise server's self-signed certificate for integration. I have SSL error and trying to follow [resolving PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message guide](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message) which I successfully done in Windows.

In Windows Jenkins installation, it has its own JENKINS_HOME/jre folder where lib/security/cacerts can be found.

**Question 1**:  Where/How to find jre used by Jenkins in MacOS?

So far, what I have found is the java_home which is in

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

But this one I am not so sure as my next steps' results were failing.

**Question 2**:How to add the truststore and password for the modified cacerts file to jenkins startup?

Using the jre in /usr/libexec/java_home, I have copied the /jre/lib/security/cacerts to my JENKINS_HOME/custom-keystore/cacerts and imported the self-signed certificate there.

```
sudo keytool -importcert -alias github -file JENKINS_HOME/custom-keystore/selfsigned.cer -keystore JENKINS_HOME/custom-keystore/cacerts
```

After that, I modified the Jenkins startup arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacert
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

using:

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci.plist Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore JENKINS_HOME/custom-keystore/cacerts
defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci.plist Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword changeit
```

then restarted Jenkins using:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

After this, I faced various issues:

1. Proxy Issue - (resolved after adding the server URL in proxylist - macOS network config)
2. The GitHub and other previously successful integrations are now having the following error:

   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

**Other Questions**
Is there anything I missed in my steps?

Is the way I add the arguments in Jenkins startup correct? (In Windows, I just modified jenkins.xml, also used arguments with "-", while here seems "-" is not needed?)

Since I am using Launch Daemon instead of Launch Agent, do I have to restart the system? -Or the defaults unload and load should suffice for the changes to apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successfully resolved the issues now. 
I corrected 1 step, and then added another step.

1. Instead of using the

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci.plist Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/custom-keystore/cacerts`

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci.plist Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword changeit`

I edited the `jenkins_runner.sh` which is found in `/Library/Application\ Support/Jenkins`:

```
javaArgs="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/custom-keystore/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

2. (restart) After executing the

   `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

   `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

I found that the changes I made did not apply completely. So I had to **restart** my mac.

It turns out that the Java/JRE in the /usr/libexec/java_home which I used for the keytool and importing cacerts is the correct one.